# When is there an $m$ that divides $u^{an+b}+v^{cn+d}$ for all $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

This is a generalization of
[Prove by induction that $73\mid 8^{(n+2)}+9^{(2n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/723832/prove-by-induction/723862)
which asks how to prove that
$73$ divides
$8^{n+2}+9^{2n+1}
$for all $n$.

Here is my generalization:
Find conditions on
 positive integers
$u, a, v, c$
and non-negative integers
$b, d$,
such that
there exists an $m$
which divides
$f(n) = u^{an+b}+v^{cn+d}$
for all $n$.
Determine $m$
in terms of
$u, a, b, v, c, d$.

Here is what I have done so far:

My solution is to write
$f(n+1)$ in terms of
$f(n)$ and see what happens.

$\begin{array}\\
f(n+1) 
&= u^{a(n+1)+b}+v^{c(n+1)+d}\\
&= u^{an+a+b}+v^{cn+c+d}\\ 
&= u^a u^{an+b}+v^c v^{cn+d}\\ 
&= (u^a-v^c+v^c) u^{an+b}+v^c v^{cn+d}\\ 
&= (u^a-v^c) u^{an+b}+v^c (u^{an+b}+v^{cn+d})\\
&= (u^a-v^c) u^{an+b}+v^c f(n)\\ 
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $(u^a-v^c)|f(n)$
for some $n$,
it divides $f(m)$
for all $m \ge n$.

Since 
$f(0) = u^b+v^d$,
if
$(u^a-v^c)|(u^b+v^d)$,
it divides $f(n)$
for all $n$.

For the original problem,
$(u, a, b, v, c, d)
=(8, 1, 2, 9, 2, 1)
$,
so $u^a-v^c
=8^1-9^2
=-73$
and
$u^b+v^d
=8^2+9^1
=73$,
so $73|f(n)$
for all $n$.

To replicate this
more generally,
we want
(assuming $v^c > u^a$)
$v^c-u^a = u^b+v^d$
or
$v^c-v^d = u^a+u^b$.
For this to hold,
we must have
$c > d$ and,
if $A = max(a, b)$
and $B = min(a, b)$,
$v^d(v^{c-d}-1) = u^B(u^{A-B}+1)
$.
If $(u, v) = 1$,
this implies that
$v^d = u^{A-B}+1$
and
$u^B = v^{c-d}-1$.

Writing the first of these as
$v^d u^B = u^A+u^B$
and substituting the second,
we get
$v^d (v^{c-d}-1) 
= u^A+v^{c-d}-1$ 
or
$v^d (v^{c-d}-1) = u^A+v^{c-d}-1$
or
$u^A = v^{c-d}(v^d-1)-v^d+1
=(v^{c-d}-1)(v^d-1)$

(Now I'm playing around,
looking for solutions.)

If $c-d = d$ (or $c = 2d$),
we get
$u^A = (v^d-1)^2$,
so a solution is always
$A=2$ and
$u = v^d-1$.
Since $u^B = v^{c-d}-1
=v^d-1 = u$,
$B = 1$.

If $c = d+1$,
$u^A = v(v^d-1)-v^d+1
= (v-1)v^d-v+1
=(v-1)(v^d-1)$.
If $d=1$,
a solution to this is 
always $u = v-1$
and
$A = 2$.

That's all I've got.

Answer (score 2):

Base case $\,n=0\,$ is true $\iff u^b \equiv - v^d.\,$ Assume so. The next case $\,n=1\,$ is true iff $\,u^{a+b}\equiv-v^{c+d}\iff u^a\equiv v^c,\,$ by canceling above, asssuming $\,u,v\,$ units. Assuming so

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&\qquad\quad u^a&\equiv& v^c\\
{\rm times}\ \ &&\ u^{an+b} &\equiv& -v^{cn+d}\\
\Rightarrow\ \ && u^{a(n+1)+b}&\equiv& -v^{c(n+1)+d}\quad\text{is the induction step}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: For motivation see a simple special case in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/724227/242)

Comment: Doubt: I would have expected the cancellation to give $u^a \equiv \color{#00ff00}{+}v^c$ otherwise the congruence product rule doesn't work.

Comment: @Anant A sign typo was introduced during a copy, now fixed, thanks.

Comment: What is the modulus of your congruences? Also, can your solution generate additional values of $m$?

Comment: @marty Any modulus that satisfies the assumptions, i.e. any common divisor of $\, u^a-v^c,\, u^b+v^d\,$ that is coprime to $\,u.$