# prove that for every integer,$ n$, greater than $1$,$ (3^{2n+1}) + (5^{2n-1})$ is divisible by $16$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Could someone please help me out with this proof?

Prove that for every integer $n≥1$, $3^{2n+1} + 5^{2n-1}$, is divisible by $16$.

I get to a point where I have...

$$3^{2k+1} \cdot 3^2 + 5^{2k-1} \cdot 5^2 $$

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918392/mathmatical-induction/918397#918397

Answer (score 2):

The order of $3$ and $5$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^*$ is four, hence you need to check the claim only for two cases: $n=1$ and $n=2$. For the remaining cases, just use the fact that:
$$3^{2(n+2)+1}\equiv 3^{2n+1}\pmod{16},\qquad 5^{2(n+2)-1}\equiv 5^{2n-1}\pmod{16}.$$

Comment: very nice solution +1.

Answer (score 2):

Do it by induction: Base case $n=1$: $3^{3}+5=32$.

Now, $$\begin{eqnarray*}3^{2(n+1)+1}+5^{2(n+1)-1}&=&3^2\cdot3^{2n+1}+5^2\cdot 5^{2n-1}\\&=&3^2\cdot3^{2n+1}+3^2\cdot5^{2n-1}+16\cdot 5^{2n-1}\\&=&3^2\cdot (3^{2n+1}+5^{2n-1})+16\cdot 5^{2n-1},\end{eqnarray*}$$
which is divisible by $16$, since the second term is clearly divisible by $16$, while the first term is divisible by $16$ by induction hypothesis.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: right- let me edit it.. thanks.

Comment: I improved formatting, hope you don't mind. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Let us first just change shift the index by 1 to make calculations easier. Then we need to show that
$$3^{2(n+1)+1}+5^{2(n+1)-1}\equiv0 \pmod{16}\quad \forall n\ge0$$
Now, $25\equiv9\pmod{16}$ and $3^{2(n+1)+1}+5^{2(n+1)-1}=9^{n}\cdot27+25^{n}\cdot5$ so
$$\begin{align*}&3^{2(n+1)+1}+5^{2(n+1)-1}\pmod{16} \\
\equiv &9^{n}\cdot27+25^{n}\cdot5\pmod{16}\\
\equiv &9^{n}\cdot27+9^{n}\cdot5\pmod{16} \\
\equiv &9^n\cdot32\pmod{16} \\
\equiv &0\pmod{16} \quad \blacksquare\end{align*}$$

Comment: Or, before shifting: $3^{2n+1}+5^{2n-1} = 9^n\cdot 3 + 25^n\cdot5^{-1} \equiv 9^n\cdot 3+9^n\cdot(-3)=0\pmod{16}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed! I shall make the edit once I come back from my trip.

Answer (score -1):

I generalized this here:
[When is there an $m$ that divides $u^{an+b}+v^{cn+d}$ for all $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724282/when-is-there-an-m-that-divides-uanbvcnd-for-all-n)

I asked:
Find conditions on
 positive integers
$u, a, v, c$
and non-negative integers
$b, d$,
such that
there exists an $m$
which divides
$f(n) = u^{an+b}+v^{cn+d}$
for all $n$.
Determine $m$
in terms of
$u, a, b, v, c, d$.

One conclusion was
that if
$(u^a-v^c)|(u^b+v^d)$,
it divides $f(n)$
for all $n$.

In this case,
putting $n+1$ for $n$
(so $d$ is not negative),
$(u, a, v, c, b, d)
=
(3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1)
$,
so
$u^a-v^c
=3^2-5^2
=-16
$
and
$u^b+v^d
=3^3+5^1
=27+5
=32
$.
Since $-16$ divides $32$,
$16$ divide all terms.

Comment: This is unlikely to be at all helpful to the OP.

Comment: Maybe not, but it *is* likely to help those who want to solve this type of problem. Besides, it is a solution. I can understand downvoting an incorrect solution, but downvoting a correct solution?